# How to prevent countdown timer from resetting when webpage is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am designing a website and I integrated a 5 minute countdown timer that starts when the web-page is loaded, using JavaScript. However, since I am more of a designer than a developer, I don't know how to edit the JavaScript code to make it so that the timer does not restart when the webpage is reloaded. I know I have to store the users cookies, and I've searched online, but the javascript code didnt work when I inserted the code. Would anyone here be able to help me out? Thank you!

Here is the javascript code for the 5 minute timer:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + " " + " " + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this approach where the time is stored in local storage of the browser and hence on refresh will not reset:

:HTML CODE:

```
<div id="time">

</div>
```

:JS CODE:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + " " + " " + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
  console.log(parseInt(seconds))
  window.localStorage.setItem("seconds",seconds)
  window.localStorage.setItem("minutes",minutes)
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  sec  = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("seconds"))
  min = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("minutes"))

  if(parseInt(min*sec)){
    var fiveMinutes = (parseInt(min*60)+sec);
  }else{
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
  }
    // var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Here is the working model of the same in the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GymRNV?editors=1011

P.S: couldn't use it here as it is a sandbox and cant access localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use web "Session storage" api for this case. it will much help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I'm rather a complete novice in JS, so should I just copy the code and replace "field" and "field.value"?

Answer (score 0):

sorry var distance = localStorage.getItem("mytime") - now;var x =localStorage.getItem("mytime"); I spent about 6 weeks figuring this out,it works,you need localstorage but only on countdown,now still has to function so counter counts,countdown is the anchor,look at w3school there countdown is set thats why it works,and thats were you use localstorage

Answer (score -1):

use w3 school countdown timer,countdown date use localstorage.mytime=setDate(d.getDate + 7),also at end if distance < 0;localStorageremoveItem, thats it ,run code